# React Native mobile app socket.io - cannot restart connection after couple hours of inactivity

Tags: node.js, react-native, websocket, socket.io, google-cloud-run

I've been working on a React Native mobile app which talks to the back-end using [socket.io](https://socket.io). If my app stays "inactive" (background mode, not killed) for a while (at least couple hours), it cannot reconnect to the server when it becomes "active" without restarting the app.

***Stack:***

**Front-End**

- React Native
- [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)

**Back-End**

- Node.js
- Express.js
- [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)
- Google Cloud Platform - [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) service

***Front-End React Native Code***

```html
const socketRef = useRef<Socket>();
...
const connect = () => {
  socketRef.current = io(apiUrl, {
    auth: {
      token: accessToken,
    },
  });
  // Event listeners
  socketRef.current.on(...
  socketRef.current.on(...
};
...
const disconnect = {
  socketRef.current?.removeAllListeners();
  socketRef.current?.disconnect();
  socketRef.current = undefined;
};
...
// Wait until Cloud Run service starts
const waitServerResponse = async () => {
  try {
    await fetch(`${apiUrl}/healthcheck`);
  } catch (error) {
    log.error('Error checking server status: ', error);
  }
};
...
// Wake up the server and reconnect when app state comes back to active from background mode
useEffect(() => {
  const stateChangeHandler = async (newAppState: string) => {
    if (newAppState === 'active') {
      if (socketRef.current && !socketRef.current.connected) {
        await waitServerResponse();
        socketRef.current.connect();
      }
    }
  };
  const appStateSubscription = AppState.addEventListener(
    'change',
    stateChangeHandler,
  );
  return () => {
    appStateSubscription.remove();
  };
}, []);
...
const resetConnection = async () => {
  disconnect();
  await waitServerResponse();
  connect();
};
...
// Some user activity
const onButtonClick = () => {
  // The connection should be active based on stateChangeHandler, if it's still not connected - hard reset of socket instance
  if (!socketRef.current.connected) {
    resetConnection();
  }
  ...
};
```

***Actual Behavior***

Success: If the app stays in a background mode for about an hour, the Cloud Run container gets stopped. When the app gets back to active, front-end makes a GET request to the back-end, waits until a container gets up and running and then reconnects via websocket.

Failed: If the app stays in a background mode for a while (6-8 hours), the Cloud Run container gets stopped. When the app gets back to active, front-end makes a GET request to the back-end, waits until a container gets up, but then front-end connot reconnect via websocket - emits and listeners don't work, no activity logs on the back-end, container is running but no activity received. If I restart the app it works immediately, e.g. it can create a new connection.

***Expected Behavior***

If the app stays in a background mode for a while (6-8 hours), it should be able to reset/create a new connection when comes back to active.